# How do you set the number of required succesful scalacheck tests

Tags: scalacheck

in [munit](https://scalameta.org/munit/) scalacheck, how do I limit the number of inputs required to pass the test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your test extends `munit.ScalaCheckSuite`, there is a protected `def scalaCheckTestParameters` you can override to set the test parameters. A good way to set it is to modify the value in the base class, for example

```
class MyTestSuite extends munit.ScalaCheckSuite {
  override val scalaCheckTestParameters = super.scalaCheckTestParameters.withMinSuccessfulTests(10)

  property("my property") {
    ...
  }
}
```